# Highcharts addSeries not showing line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

For my chart's data source, I am calling a web service, parsing the response into an array and then attempting to use the array in addSeries. The data does get added to my chart but instead of a line chart, it just shows the points and labels (despite the data series being set at 'line'). I am curious as to why the line isn't being rendered.

Here is a sample of the data being returned from my web service.

```
Time,Summary
9/2/2015 12:00:00 AM,209
9/2/2015 12:15:00 AM,207
9/2/2015 12:30:00 AM,196
9/2/2015 12:45:00 AM,200
9/2/2015 1:00:00 AM,202
9/2/2015 1:15:00 AM,208
9/2/2015 1:30:00 AM,208
9/2/2015 1:45:00 AM,206
9/2/2015 2:00:00 AM,211
9/2/2015 2:15:00 AM,220
9/2/2015 2:30:00 AM,203
9/2/2015 2:45:00 AM,202
9/2/2015 3:00:00 AM,210
9/2/2015 3:15:00 AM,205
9/2/2015 3:30:00 AM,209
9/2/2015 3:45:00 AM,207
9/2/2015 4:00:00 AM,210
9/2/2015 4:15:00 AM,198
9/2/2015 4:30:00 AM,210
9/2/2015 4:45:00 AM,205
9/2/2015 5:00:00 AM,212
9/2/2015 5:15:00 AM,203
9/2/2015 5:30:00 AM,197
9/2/2015 5:45:00 AM,203
9/2/2015 6:00:00 AM,211
9/2/2015 6:15:00 AM,256
9/2/2015 6:30:00 AM,235
9/2/2015 6:45:00 AM,214
9/2/2015 7:00:00 AM,201
9/2/2015 7:15:00 AM,205
9/2/2015 7:30:00 AM,198
9/2/2015 7:45:00 AM,215
9/2/2015 8:00:00 AM,195
9/2/2015 8:15:00 AM,197
9/2/2015 8:30:00 AM,195
9/2/2015 8:45:00 AM,191
9/2/2015 9:00:00 AM,203
9/2/2015 9:15:00 AM,211
```

Here's where I call the web service and parse the csv data.

```
var dataSeries = [];
$.get('GetMyData',{}, function (csv) {
                var lines = csv.split('\n');
                $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
                    var items = line.split(',');
                    if (lineNo !== 0) {
                        var x = +new Date(items[0]),
                        summary = parseInt(items[1]);
                        dataSeries.push([x, summary]);
                    }
                });
```

Here's where I setup and render my chart.

```
var options = { 
                chart: {
                       backgroundColor: '#f6f6f6',
                       renderTo: 'chart' + chartNum
                       },
                xAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Hour'
                        },
                        type: 'datetime',
                        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                            day: '%b %e %l:%M %P',
                            hour: '%l:%M %P'
                        },                    
                    },
                yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Average Whatever'
                        },
                        min: 0,
                 },
                 plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: []
            };
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                chart.addSeries({
                    name: 'Summaries',       
                    data: dataSeries,
                    type: 'line',
                    marker: { enabled: true }
                    });
```

My chart ends up looking something like this:

[image]

Comment: I think you would need to provide the same data as visible on the screenshot. Basing on your code snippets I've created a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/5s76umne/) but I can see the line there.

Comment: I just edited it so that the data and screenshot correspond.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there was a newline at the end of the data returned from the web service. I added a condition to check for a blank line and all is well.

```
if ((lineNo !== 0)&&(line != "")) {
..parse data into array
}
```

Comment: You'd better trim the csv before splitting it:
    var lines = csv.trim().split('\n');

Comment: You could do `var lines = csv.trim().split('\n');` too.